# In the United States,what does it mean for a website to keep records for legal compliance? And what is typically kept?

Tags: united-states, legal-terms

Mediafire claims they delete or do not store Logs of who access your account in their data retention policy. However, in there data retention policy they state they keep records for legal compliance for up to 10 years. What does a website typically keep for legal compliance? For example, in their TOS they state:

- ***"Information about your devices plus your browser information, browser history, IP address, the Internet Service Provider (ISP) you use, your geolocation and system configuration information is recorded."***

[image]

- If they **Claim to keep no logs of who access your account** then what's kept for legal compliance?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is really no way to know what they retain, beyond what they state in their TOS. There is no law in the US requiring or forbidding such logs, so they can keep whatever they think will be helpful to them if a legal problem should arise.

Comment: What if I asked someone from support and they said they did not keep any logs? can they lie to me about that or is that not legal? and that chart is what they say any law enforcement can request for an account holder.

Comment: @Cj25 They can lie. But if the lie is intended to induce you to take action, such as doing business with them, and if it is reasonable for you to rely on their false statement, **and** if the lie causes materiel damage to you, they have committed fraud and in theory you could sue. Proving all that in court, and proving enough damages to more than cover the cost of the suit is not trivial. Most people won't bother, and they probably know that. Or they might mean they don't keep logs **available without a subpoena**.

Comment: Also, "someone from support" may only know what logs they can access, and not even know about logs which are kept but on a very restricted basis.

Comment: yea the two pictures i added just now in my post were from there support

Comment: would that be a lie or false statement where i could sue

Comment: @Cj25 To sue you would have to prove material misstatement at least. That the statement was not only false, but made a significant difference to you, and would to any reasonable person in your position. You might need to prove knowing falsehood, i.e a lie. You would need a lawyer to even start that. That is as far as i can go, for more you'll need to consult a lawyer.